# List of thorough Space Journals

Tags: reference-request, research

I am trying to get a list of rounded and comprehensive journals related to Space and Aeronautics, not  only covering the latest news and achievements in the field but also publishing interesting researches or surveys or explaining topics as trajectory optimization or the numerical methods involved.

The only one I have found so far is "The Journal of The Astronautical Sciences".

Comment: https://www.aiaa.org/publications/journals

Comment: https://ieee-aess.org/publications/transactions-aes

Comment: https://www.tsijournals.com/journals/journal-of-space-exploration.html

Comment: https://www.journals.elsevier.com/advances-in-space-research

Comment: @NgPh you're on a roll! I think you can just start a Community Wiki answer https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny8LI.png (perhaps add an annotation for which are purely paywalled, which have some articles as open access, and which are purely open access)

Comment: @uhoh, I am always puzzled when someone asks "How come I cannot find..." when a simple Google query returns multiple positive outcomes. There could be something hidden in the question that I haven't understood, or the person doesn't know that Google (and other search engines) exists.

Comment: @NgPh do the ones you've listed fit the description and the criteria outlined in the question? If they are just the result of a cursory search and may not actually be what the OP described, *then yes, they should not be posted in an answer*, wiki or otherwise.

Comment: @uhoh, exactly. The OP should clarify that.