# What are opinions of most planetary scientists on this study (link below), were there already some complex reviews in scientific journals?

Tags: oxygen, exoplanet

I remember this two year old article from *Universe Today* https://www.universetoday.com/144402/science-fiction-might-be-right-after-all-there-might-be-breathable-atmospheres-across-the-universe/ about this study [Stepwise Earth oxygenation is an inherent property of global biogeochemical cycling](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/237067780.pdf) by Lewis J. Alcott, Benjamin J. W. Mills, Simon W. Poulton of the School of Earth and Environment, University of Leeds, in the UK.

In summary, widely accepted the three-step model of Earth’s oxygenation outlines three major shifts in Earth’s history, with each one substantially altering the Earth’s atmosphere by adding more oxygen. The history of Earth’s oxygenation is complicated, it wasn’t a linear progression and a certain level of luck is required to create an oxygen-rich world. Based on this, exoplanets with oxygen rich breathable atmosphere should be extremely rare.

The authors of this study created different model where stepwise Earth oxygenation is an inherent property of global biogeochemical cycling and based on this model, once the Earth had the right microbes and plate tectonics, which were both established 3 billion years ago, it was only a matter of time before it reached the oxygen level it has now, regardless of volcanic activity and land-based plants. That means that exoplanets with oxygen rich breathable atmospheres could be much more common than was previously thought.

What are the opinions of the majority of planetary scientists on this study. Were there already some complex reviews in scientific journals. Despite that study is almost 2 years old and on very important topic, I could not find any reviews for example in scientific journals mentioned in this answer [List of thorough Space Journals](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55266/list-of-thorough-space-journals).

Edit: This question was asked also in Astronomy SE, because it could be more suitable forum for this topic link  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47060/what-are-opinions-of-most-planetary-scientists-on-this-study-link-below-were

Comment: This subject is more in the field of [cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmology) than [astronautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronautics). Have you tried to ask Astronomy SE? Have you tried Googling "Cosmology" "Astrophysics"? You may fing journals of interest (I hope).

Comment: OK. I ask this also in Astronomy SE. Can this question stay open in both forums. Or must be then closed in this one. I could not find any reviews in scientific journals related to this topic.

Comment: I haven't requested a closure of your question. But if you ask exactly the same question on Astronomy SE, in my opinion, you should link to that one.

Comment: @DavidCage In Stack Exchange cross-posting the same question in multiple sites (i.e. "I [ask this also in Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47060/7982)") is strongly discouraged. You should probably delete one copy before someone starts downvoting both for cross-posting. I agree that solar system formation is much more on-topic in Astronomy SE than Space SE. There aren't really space exploration aspects to this, we can't send a rocket to check this out. However I wonder if [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) isn't actually the best site for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted to Astronomy.SE. Cross-posting is not highly regarded (I'm being nice), and this is more on topic there than here.

Comment: @uhoh Earth Science SE is about the Earth. This question is a better fit at Astronomy SE.

Comment: @DavidHammen in addition to "Earth" being mentioned six times, the question is asking about the study titled "Stepwise Earth oxygenation is an inherent property of global biogeochemical cycling" by folks from the "School of Earth and Environment" so this question seems to me to be spot-on for Earth Science SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not on-topic here in Astronomy SE (and we should never consider anything other than being nice!) As mentioned in a few of my comments it's probably suitable for Astronomy SE or Earth Science SE, being about Earth and all.

Comment: @uhoh I think perhaps you voted to close for the wrong reason; this is Space Exploration.SE, not Astronomy.SE. It is not on topic in Earth Sciences.SE, in my (strong) opinion. Astronomy.SE is the best site; there are already several questions about astrobiology there.

Comment: @DavidHammen you've expressed your opinion, I've expressed mine.

Comment: @uhoh I was just expressing my opinion that your comment "I’m voting to close this question because it is not on-topic here in Astronomy SE" is ... weird. This is Space Exploration.SE, not Astronomy.SE. Perhaps you meant to vote to close the cross-post in Astronomy.SE?

Comment: @DavidHammen Ng Ph wrote that this question is more suited for Astronomy SE, so I posted it also there. I asked if cross-posting in two forums is banned by the rules, but he replied that I should only post link to Astronomy SE. question. As I replied to you on Astronomy SE, I don't think that this question is opinion based.

Comment: Anyway it doesn't matter, there weren't any reviews of this study yet and based on list of citations posted in linked question, reception of most planetary scientists was mixed. So everyone who is interested in this topic can go through citations list and make up his own opinion. If mods. want to close this question I am fine with it. I just don't want delete it, so linked question with citations list can stay here for readers who are interested in this topic.